# Cloudbees RUN@cloud select Java 1.8

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, cloudbees

I am using Jenkings on Cloudbees and I would like to **change the JDK version to 1.8**.
I followed the tutorial at developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/PreInsatlledJDKs. However, I fail at step 10 -> There is no such option to choose the JDK. Where can I change this?

**UPDATE**: I made some screenshots to better explain my problem.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkl7V.png) is the jenkins configuration for the JDK. As you can see, I only have one JDK selected and it's Java 8.

However, if I view my "System Information", everything looks like Java 7. It says that "java.home" still points to "/opt/java7/jre" and "java.runtime.version" points to "1.7.0_25-b15" for example.

Not surprisingly, the compilation process of my maven project [fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JuCb.png), because for the maven compiler plugin I specified 1.8 as source and target java version.

Comment: I would ask this to CloudBees support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one single JDK, then you won't see that option, cause it will pick it up by default.

You will se the JDK option with the drop down menu if you have more than 1 JDK configured in your jenkinsURL/configure.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I indeed had only on JDK selected. Still, I can't use java 8. I edited my post to provide some more information about my problem.

Comment: That's weird, I can use it smoothly on mine. Try these few things:

Comment: weird it works smoothly on my instance. Try these few things: 1) uncheck the "install automatically" option and leave only the "use preinstalled JDK" option 2)try to add another JDK and manually select JAVA 8 in your job 3)restart your instance <yourjenkinsurl>/restart. If you still cannot get it, open a support ticket on cloudbees.

Comment: Thank you!! It works now!! I added a further JDK (now I have "java 7" and "java 8"), and then the JDK drop-down list appeared in the project configuration page and I chose "java 8" and now the build process runs with the right JDK.